# How to Use D-Noise in the Compositor?

Tags: rendering, add-on, compositing-nodes, noise-reduction, denoise

Basically the question.
Usually, I let Blender save some additional render passes (mostly ID masks) together with my main rendering for later, in-depth compositing. In the compositor, I pick the image, environment and all my other passes and feed them into a File Output node.

Today I wanted to try the D-Noise add-on (for it got recommended to me), and it worked well in the rendering window itself. However, the saved files were all noisy, which means that D-Noise doesn't seem to recognize render passes being fed through the compositor by default. Is there any way to connect the "denoised image" to a File Output node in the compositor (manually saving won't be a solution of course)?

Comment: I have the same question! If I find out, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've worked it out: in the Compositor, remove the Render Layers node and add an Image Node and a Denoise Node like this:

[image]

Now open the first image in your sequence, tell the Image Node that this is indeed an Image Seqeunce and choose the number of frames it has.

[image]

Now you can render as usual and see the result, either as a single image or as an animation. Specify the number of frames to be rendered and your output path as if this was a 3D scene.

Note that the results of applying D-NOISE this way are far inferior to applying it during a render. I guess OptiX has a lot more information to work with when the 3D scene is loaded, as opposed to seeing only the 2D image. Here's a comparison between D-NOISE when a applied with a render, and after the fact. Notice the loss of detail in the second image.

[image]

[image]

In regards to D-NOISE not kicking in: try starting Blender as an Administrator (if it's a Windows system). I've had the same issue with some of my nodes, when run as Administrator D-NOISE behaves fine.

Hope this helps!